# Show TreeSet in Scala / Java

Tags: java, scala, collections, treeset

Is there a way, in Scala, to print a TreeSet in a way it stored in the memory?
For example, in case I initialize a tree

```
val tree_1: TreeSet[Int] = TreeSet(4, 2, 1)
```

I would expect to see something like -

```
    4
   /
  2
 /
1
```

But when I try to approach to root, all I can see is -

```
println(tree_1.head) //>> 1
println(tree_1.firstKey) //>> 1
```

Same happens for

```
val tree_2: TreeSet[Int] = TreeSet(2, 1, 4)
```

I would expect to see -

```
    2
   / \
  1   4
```

But I get the same result -

```
println(tree_2.head) //>> 1
println(tree_2.firstKey) //>> 1
```

Edit -
If I wasn't clear, I want to print everything from top to bottom in the way it was initialized in the memory, not in ascending order. I know that `.head` or `.firstKey` are supposed to return only a value and not a Tree, I would like it to return the root value, then go to the right/left branch, print the value and keep going.

Comment: `head` and `firstKey` both return an element in the collection and with using `println` you are seeing the string representation of the item. However, even if you were to print the collection itself, you would still see `TreeSet(2, 1, 4)` as the output. That's because the main purpose of a `TreeSet` is that of being a `Set`, more specifically a `SortedSet`. The fact that it's implemented as a tree is an implementation detail. You can read more about it here (referring to 2.8-2.12): https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html#red-black-trees

Comment: Of course it is, if I wasn't clear, I wanted to print everything from top to bottom in the way it was initialized in the memory, not in ascending order.

Comment: If you ask for the first item, you should expect the first item according to the sorting criteria you provided (which is natural sorting for most built-in types). I don't think that `TreeSet` supports tree traversal operations, since it's there mostly as an implementation of a `SortedSet`. If it's not possible via the API you might want to get in touch with the Scala team and see if that could be a viable contribution. Can you clarify for me what is it that you ultimately want to achieve? Printing a tree following BFS doesn't seem an end goal, unless yours is pure exploration for learning.

Comment: You're right, that's only for practice and playing. Nevertheless, it still sounds weird that there is no option to verify the hierarchy of the tree in the memory.

Comment: `TreeSet` is actually smarter than you think. The tree is _self-balancing_, both trees in your example will actually look _the same_.  So, if you want to "go from top to bottom", find the middle, place it on top, then go down a level, and repeat for left and right.

Comment: Dima, is there an option in Scala for a simple Tree which doesn't move the elements and just store them ordered by FIFO?

Comment: @MaorAharon I don't think there is a library class like that (it wouldn't be very useful), but you can implement it yourself, it's fairly straight-forward. Though, I am not sure what you mean by "FIFO" in this context. There _is_ a FIFO Queue implementation in scala, but it is not a tree ...